# What is Pablo coffee?

Tags: coffee-culture

It's mentioned in a book called Jasper Jones by the Australian author Craig Silvey. There's a child, a teenager I think, that's given it by their parent. I've never heard of it before. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pablo coffee was an **Australian brand of instant coffee** that was a [household staple in the 60s and 70s](https://amp.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/australia-food-blog/2013/oct/08/ironman-geisha-ludicrous-coffee-fetishism) and still [advertised in the 80s](https://youtube.com/watch?v=m3uSVIZEuvM).

After that, it seems to have disappeared from the market.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I'd never heard of it and thought it was odd that coffee would be given to kids, but I guess that's what happened in those day.

Answer (score 2):

Pablo coffee was considered poor quality, even for an instant coffee.
It was powdered, with a bitter taste. The name was derided for its cheapness.
In the 1960's- 1980's there wasn't  a wide variety of coffee's in australia, and price ruled over quality.
The closest brand today, in terms of the above, would be *International Roast*

Answer (score 1):

The old Pablo Coffee was terrible - down there with International Roast and Caterer's Blend.

Pablo is still available but is now a freeze dried coffee of good quality; however, older people like me won't touch it.